# How do you remove the href value and combine with text?

Tags: c#

I have a string of HTML text. I want to take the `href` attribute from each `<a>` tag and combine it with the text in the tag.

For example,

```html
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Hello World!</a>
```

should become

```html
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Hello World! (www.stackoverflow.com)</a>
```

Parenthesis preferred but not required.

Comment: on the server or client ?

Comment: where are those hrefs? can you explain the hierarchy?

Comment: The href is an attribute within the opening <a> tag. The <a> tags can be anywhere in the string. The visible text or label portion of the <a> tag does not contain any tags - just plain text.

Comment: I am talking about control hierarchy because you need some sort of recursive function in order to be able to locate the anchors and change the text into text + (url)

Comment: can you show us any of your html? you're not expecting someone to write the code for you, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to work for my initial test cases.  I used two capture groups and a then replaced the second with the second + the first

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = @"<a href=""www.stackoverflow.com"">Hello World!</a> <a href=""www.secondsite.com"">Second Site!</a> <a href=""www.thirdsite.com"">Third Site!</a>";

        var pattern = "(?<=href=\")([^\">]+)([^<]*)";
        var newText = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "$1$2 ($1)");

        Console.WriteLine(newText);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

there are probably some edge cases that it'll fail out on

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing it in CSS ?

```
/* HTML */
<a href="http://www.google.com">My link</a>

/* CSS */
a:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}

/* Result */
My link (http://www.google.com)
```

See here : http://jsfiddle.net/0fvkLzrc/

If you don't want CSS, I would recommend HTML Agility Pack, it's better than a regex or anything similar. You'll be able to loop for your links and modify their properties.